# Date in the URL with The Events Calendar

Tags: plugins, the-events-calendar

I am somewhat of a Wordpress beginner so please excuse any ignorance.

I have installed the plugin The Events Calendar (http://tri.be/wordpress-events-calendar/) and it works pretty much perfectly. One issue I have is the URL format for an event, which based on the URL slug is `/upcoming-event/[event title]/`. If I have multiple events of the same name, the URL looks like `/upcoming-event/[event title]-2/`.

This is undesirable, I would prefer to have URLs more like that possible with posts `/upcoming-event/[year]/[month]/[event title]`. On a whim, I attempted to copy in the format used for posts `/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/` but alas, no luck.

I had a quick check to make sure it wasn't a PRO feature but it doesn't appear to be. So does anyone know if this is possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try to change the slug to the value you need for each event. The problem arises if you have the same event twice (or more) in the same month though. You will need to create a new title for the event.

you can try this plug-in:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks

It might help you with changing the permalink structure for the events so you wont need to keep changing the slugs when you create events. But I don't think that will help with removing the  number after the event title as that is the way WP core works for duplicate posts.

Tri.be has a pretty good support team have you posted the question there?

Comment: Thank you Ken. I really like that plug in you suggested, works very well. Reading up about the number added on I realise the problem is much bigger than I first thought, affecting posts in exactly the same way - I don't seem to be the first to have come across this either. As my site is only small I can live with the number, ugly as it is. Regarding Tri.be support, being a free user I can only read the forums, not sign up and post.

Comment: It's a long shot but you could ask it in the WP support page: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/the-events-calendar The other option is to just make the URL unique. That is why the -2,-3, etc. is added it has to be a unique URL for WP. The title of the page can be the same just make the slug have the month-day-year when you create the event. I ran across this with our church website using the events calendar. There are repeated events every month. I just don't feel it's that big of a deal the URL has the number added.